# Multiple objects referencing shared object (chess game)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

This question is about design and the implications of many objects in a system holding references to the same object. I've encountered this issue in other projects, but I think it's particularly applicable to my current project. Is there any guidance as to whether either design should be avoided for reasons unforeseen?

The examples involve a chess program I'm working on. They're not representative of my actual code, so no need to comment on the quality of the code which has obviously been sacrificed for the purpose of brevity.

### First design

```
public class Piece
{
    private Board board;
    private PieceType type;
    private Color color;
    private Square location;

    public Piece(PieceType type, Color color, Board board, Square square)
    {
        // assignments to members
    }

    public Move[] moves()
    {
        type.moves(board, location);
    }
}

public final class Board // Board is immutable
{
    // Would have to manage pieces with duplicate squares
    private List<Piece> pieces;

    public Board placePiece(PieceType type, Color color, Square square)
    {
        Piece p = new Piece(type, color, this, square);
        pieces.add(piece);
    }

    public Move[] moves(Square fromLocation)
    {
        Piece p = pieces.get(fromLocation);
        return p.moves();
    }
}
```

I abandoned this design where each `Piece` held a reference to the `Board` at construction. 
I think it's awkward for the `Piece`'s to maintain this reference when they only need the `Board` in its current state at the moment they're asked to determine their available moves. I tend toward injecting dependencies in the constructor instead of methods, because it removes context from clients. However, there's something I don't like about this design, especially the fact that the pieces would have to be updated with the new board every time the board changes. Since `Board` is immutable, the `Pieces` will maintain references to `Board`s with expired states. Creating a new `Board` entails creating all new `Piece`s too, which seems like a lot of unnecessary computation; especially considering many of them won't even have `moves` invoked in a given turn, i.e., won't even take advantage of the most current `Board`.

### Second design

Would it be better to store the location information in the `Board` and pass in the board and location to the `Piece`'s `moves` method?

```
public class Piece
{
    private PieceType type;
    private Color color;

    public Piece(PieceType type, Color color)
    {
        // assignments to members
    }

    // Can pass in 
    public Move[] moves(Board board, Square location)
    {
        type.moves(board, location);
    }
}

public class Board
{
    // No duplicate squares allowed
    private Map<Square, Piece> pieces;

    public Board placePiece(PieceType type, Color color, Square square)
    {
        Piece p = new Piece(type, color);
        pieces.put(square, piece);
    }

    public Move[] moves(Square fromLocation)
    {
        Piece p = pieces.get(fromLocation);
        return p.moves(this, fromLocation);
    }
}
```

The only other way I can think to use the first design is not to pass a reference to a `Board` in the `Piece`'s constructor, rather pass a proxy with an interface that matches `Board`, but itself is updated with the current board when changes are made. That way, all pieces would always reference the most recent board.

Comment: I would expect Piece to be either an interface or abstract base class. With derived classes King, Queen, etc. And thus remove the PieceType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, a highly opinionated question, and there is no perfect answer here.  However, I believe many would agree that your insights in creating Design 2 after Design 1 are, on the whole, strong and thus make Design 2 objectively better in a number of ways.

You hit the nail on the head nice and heard with removing the `Board` reference from the `Piece` definition, and the `Square` as well.  A good OOO design principle is that Objects should only store references to that which conceptually defines them.  The `Board`, and `Square` (`BoardPosition`?) do not define the Piece.

The `moves(...)` method is a tricky one.  While the `Piece` class seems nice, I would argue that the `Board` class is better, but still not enough.  If you intend to create a fully accurate Chess implementation, you will have to design for [En passant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant), [Castling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling), and [Stalemate conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draw_%28chess%29), all of which depend not only on the current `Board` state, but previous `Board` states as well - the transactional history of the `ChessGame`, if you will.

I could go on and on here but you deserve to learn more of this for yourself.  So, I will leave a few more questionably objective nuggets for your consumption:

- Be sure to use Enums vigilantly!  `PieceType` and `Color` are perfect candidates for this.  Enums make your code precise and clear, and tend to turn nasty Runtime errors into easy Compilation errors for equivalent designs.
- Always design with your end goals in mind.  If you plan on doing some sort of AI experimentation with these classes, revisit your decision to make `Board` immutable.  This may be more prohibitive than you want for fast analysis.
- In direct contradiction with my previous point, don't worry about interfaces until you know you need at least two different implementations, and you know what they are.  Speculative abstraction is more harmful than short-term limitations.